# codeigniter Zip Encoding Class add multiple files

Tags: php, codeigniter, loops, zip

heres how I am doing now :

```
$path = "./uploads/1.txt";
$path1 =  "./uploads/4.txt";
$this->zip->read_file($path);
$this->zip->read_file($path1);
$this->zip->download('files_backup.zip');
```

Now I want to add the files from a database query which returns the path of the files .

```
$data['query'] = $this->db->get_where('files', array('uid'=>$uid));
```

now please tell me which loop that I must use in order to call     `$this->zip->read_file($path);`

from the results of the query mentioned above..

thanks

**Edit:**

```
foreach ($query->result() as $row)
{
    echo $row->filename;
}
```

**result**

```
335476sfsr.txt 
egyafhwe7g.txt
4566weyt36.txt
```

so, it just shows the files of that user ..

Comment: We need more information about your db schema, is your query returning multiple rows? seems like uid would be returning one row.  Which you wouldn't need to loop.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

ok, so then just edit the given loop like so

```
foreach ($query->result() as $row)
{
    $this->zip->read_file($row->filename);
}

$this->zip->download('files_backup.zip');
```

Comment: Hi, I have edited the question and added the result of the query.   Thanks

Comment: single file download perfectly but multiple file occur error !

Answer (score 3):

Make a database with a table ITEMS and add IMG column then use this code.

**View:**

```
 <form method='post' action='<?= base_url() ?>index.php/zip/createzip/'>
            <input type="submit" name="but_createzip1" value='Add file from path and download zip'>
 </form>
```

**Controller:**

```
public function createzip(){

      // Load zip library
      $this->load->library('zip');

      $query = $this->db->get('items');

      foreach ($query->result() as $row)
        {
          $fileName = FCPATH."./uploads/".$row->img;
          $this->zip->read_file($fileName);
        }

       $filename = "backup.zip";
       $this->zip->download($filename);
 }
```